# Can you explain the output of the following source code using little endian concept?

Tags: c, pointers

Can anyone explain me the output of the following which is based on little endian and big endian.I have read many articles and posts regarding this concept but also after doing so much stuff i'm not able to gain anything about this topic.Everything goes above my head.

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance!!!
The source code:
Consider the size of int as two bytes and size of char as one byte

```
int main()
{
   int a = 300;    
   char *b = (char *)&a;
   *++b = 2;
   printf("%d ",a);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try `a = 0x12C; // 300 ...  printf("%x\n",a);`  What does this print out for you?

Comment: It will probably print `706` on a little-endian machine.  Assuming 2-byte `int`, `300` would be stored as the bytes 0x2c, 0x01. `*++b = 2` will change the second byte to 0x02, so the storage for the `int` will contain the bytes 0x2c, 0x02. The new hexadecimal value 0x022c is 706 in decimal. On a bigendian machine, it will probably print `258`, which is 0x0102 in hex. You should be able to work out why.

Comment: I'd say people would be more willing to help you if you'd tell exactly what part of endianness concept you can't understand.

Comment: [This link](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/endian.html) should help. Google is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

First, this is technically not specified by standard, because representation of integral types is implementation dependant, and changing directly bytes in an int value could lead to a trap representation.

That being said, you declare that your implementation uses (you declared some and I assume what was left):

- 8 bits for a char (a byte and a char have *by definition* the same size)
- 2 bytes for an int (16 bits)
- no padding bits - 15 value bits and 1 sign bit in 2's complement

There are no trap representations here, and accessing any object at the byte level is allowed

Now let's see what happens:

`a` is 300 in decimal which is 0x12C in hexadecimal

In little endian representation, `(char *) &a` will point to an array of 2 characters `{ 0x2c, 1 }` - it would be `{ 1, 0x2C }` in big endian

Next `*++b = 2` first increases pointer and that assign 2 to the pointed value.

The equivalent char array is now `{ 0x2c, 2 }` in little endian and `{ 1, 2 }` in big endian.

Let's convert that back to an int and we get 0x22C = 556 in little endian and 0x102 = 258 in big endian

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned you've read about it, I assume you know the basics that little endian store least value byte first and big endian store highest value byte first (which we find intuitive).

Now consider your program. `a` is 300. Binary for 300:

00000000 00000000 00000001 00101100

On a little endian machine however, it will be stored as following.

00101100 00000001 00000000 00000000

Now you have a char that is assigned the reference to `a`

```
char *b = (char *)&a;
```

So initially `b` points to 00101100.

Next you do

```
   *++b = 2;
```

Meaning increment `b` and then assign the value 2 to where it points after increment.

So, `b` points to 00000001 after the increment and you assign 2 there. Hence it becomes 00000010.

Now seeing the whole number together, on a Little endian machine it would look like this,

00101100 00000010 00000000 00000000

Which on a little endian machine translates to `556` - which is the output you should expect.

You can understand the big endian case using the same example.